# installing programs from the bash script

Tags: installation, bash, software-center

I wish to install a large number of programs from the software center on all my 8 machines. Installing each program individually would be time consuming so I decided to write a bash script for installing all these programs in 1 go. It looks something like this -

```
#! /bin/sh
apt-get install xyz1
apt-get install xyz2
apt-get install xyz3
```

(Am running this script as a super user)

Now the problem is that for almost every installation it asks me `..need to get 123 kb of archives. Continue [Y/n] ?` Every time I have to select `Y`(yes) myself.

Is there some way in which I can override this confirming mechanism so that I don't have to press `y` everytime?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First of all, you can use

```
sudo apt-get install pkg1 pkg2 ... pkg3
```

and next, with the option `-y`, `apt-get` will not ask for confirmation.

Comment: If installation of some package, say pkg2 fails, will the installation of remaining packages still continue?

Comment: This is hard to say, it depends on the reason of fail, I think. But it not change in the "multiline" approach, because if there is a reason blocking the package manager, it will be so also in a separate command.

Comment: Thank you. And what if some pkg depends on some other package not already installed? Will it install the dependencies as well?

Comment: Yes, of course it will select for installation dependencies and recommended packages too.

Comment: The one thing to consider is that if a *dependency* is being installed, and then fails, that it will fail to install any of the packages that depend on that (i.e. if `pkg2` depends on `pkg1`, and `pkg1` fails, `pkg2`'s install fails)

Answer (score 4):

The [`yes`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/yes) command is useful here

```
yes | ./install_script.sh
```